# Pseudo div css mouse hover apply to other div

Tags: css

I have one problem, see my code

```
<style>
.box {width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red;}
.box_second {width: 200px; height: 100px; background-color: blue; display: none;}
.box:hover ~ .box_second {display: block;}
.other {width: 100%;}
</style>

<div class="box"></div>
<div class="other">
Some other content
Some other content
Some other content
</div>
<div class="box_second">Please click <a href="next">me</a> and I will show you a secrea.</div>
```

My problem is when I move mouse from .box div to .box_second the second div disappear (.box_second), how I can do one another rule to show .box_second when move mouse from first to second div or .other div?

Here is js fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/LLrcE/

Comment: of course u can't change definitively .box_second type of display when u leave first box. have u try javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the @Notulysses' idea of using a wrapper (outer div), I've adjusted it to make it work almost perfectly. I intended to post the jsfiddle as a comment under his answer but he had already deleted his answer before. So I would like to post it in an answer to help you and others who may have similar problems.

Using an outer container has a very interesting effect like this: Of course you have to set the size of the outer container to be equal to the size of your first box (the red box), but when some child element is popped out (such as by hovering on the first box and the style `display:block` is applied), we can keep the `:hover` state of the container by hovering on all the child elements including the popped out one and even including all the **middle space between child elements** (although hovering on those child elements take no effect before). That way we can keep the popped out element shown even the mouse is moved out of the first box however the mouse should be **overed on one of the child elements**. In this case that condition is almost acceptable, because when you move the mouse from the first box to the second box **straightly**, the mouse of course will be over on one of the middle child elements (including the space between child elements) and hence we have a chance to keep the second box shown until the mouse is moved out of the outer div.

Here are the code details:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="other">
      Some other content
      Some other content
      Some other content
    </div>
  <div class="box_second">Please click <a href="next">me
  </a> and I will show you a secrea.</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.outer {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
.outer:hover .box_second {display: block;}
.outer:hover * {
  pointer-events:auto;
}
.other {
  width: 300%;
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

**NOTE**: `pointer-events` works only since IE 11.

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/LLrcE/5/)